# Laravel 8 MVC how to send a value from Controller to View

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to display set of values(hashtags) which I get from DB to View through controller.
But I'm stuck at here in this controller. Not sure what function to use, `view` or `With` after getting DB values. What will be best option to use? and how to use it in view
here is my sample code of Controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Models\Hashtag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\SearchHashtagRequest;


class BannedHashController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){


        if(request()->query('query_hashtag')){
         $hashtags = HashTag::where('hashtag','LIKE',"%{request()->query('query_hashtag')}%");

        //Stuck in here
        }else{
        }

        return view('bannedhashtags.index');

    }

}
```

Index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Instagram  Hashtags</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Check your Instagram hashtags</h1>
    

   <form  method="get" type="get"   action="{{url('bannedhashtags')}}">
   <div class="input-group">
   
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." name="query_hashtag">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Go!</button>
          </span>
   
   </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a [manual page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views) for this

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below:

```
public function index(){
    if(request()->query('query_hashtag')){
             $hashtags = HashTag::where('hashtag','LIKE',"%{request()->query('query_hashtag')}%");
    
            return view('bannedhashtags.index',['hashtags'=>$hastags]);
            }
   return view('bannedhashtags.index');
}
```

and in this case you need to check for $hastags variable in your html like below

```
@if(isset($hashtags))
     your html code here if the hashtags variable is set
@endif
```

if what you are looking for is to filter the hashtags list it will be better to show the hashtags list (maybe using pagination if the list is too big) and then filter it by using ajax request.